# llenar draggable dinamicamente vuejs

Tags: array, vue.js

Estoy construyendo los siguientes "draggables": 1 que es de donde se tomarán los elementos a reacomodar, los otros bloques son los que construyo dinámicamente en base a las categorías disponibles de acomodamiento. Al final en un arreglo asociativo de objetos que diferencio por la clave de la columna en cuestión, requiero recuperar los id de los elementos almacenados. Sí se almacena en los arreglos pero no se muestran los objetos en los "draggebles" de columnas y tampoco desaparecen de la columna de donde son tomados:

```
<b-row>
<b-col cols="3">
<h6>Conceptos a ubicar</h6>
<draggable class="list-group" :list="categorias[question.id]" group="people" @change="log">
<div
class="list-group-item"
v-for="(element) in categorias[question.id]"
:key="element.uuid_opcion"
>
{{ element.opcion }}
</div>
</draggable>
</b-col>
<div v-for="(column, columnIndex) in question.preguntas.categorias" :key="columnIndex" class="column">
<b-col cols="3" md="auto">
<h6>{{column.categoria}}</h6>
<draggable class="list-group" :list="respuestas[column.id]" group="animals" @change="log">
<div
class="list-group-item"
v-for="(respuesta) in respuestas[column.id]"
:key="respuesta.uuid_opcion"
>
{{ respuesta.opcion }}
</div>
</draggable>
</b-col>
</div>
</b-row>
```